# To encode large number of IDs (100+) as feature what type of encoding is to be done?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, categorical-encoding

I am doing a project on predicting prices of air fare based on features like destination airport ID ,source airport ID and carrier name
[image]

I have a need to encode these values but the amount of distinct values for airport IDs go up to 420 different values. Could anyone suggest a method to encode these features?
I was thinking of using one hot encoding for carriers that has up to 21 different values but I also believe that is a bad idea. I look forward to hear everyone's advice.

Comment: Why do you believe that one-hot encoding is a bad idea? What’s the specific drawback here?

Comment: @Sycorax , one-hot encoding would introduce so many binary columns taking more space but there is also the fact that in the small portion of the data set shown here has 21 distinct values , but there more unprocessed data in my hand which can have up to 2000 different values for carrier. for the time being i am training models by using this data-frame but i have substituted the carriers with a numerical ID. Also i performed one-hot-encoding for all the categorical data  but now the size 10 gb and I can't read it. I have a 16 gb ram